# Custom ads in iOS app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, web, ads

I would like to include ads into my iOS app. I don't want to use iAd, because I don't have that many impressions on my app (it is an app made for a very limited audience) and because of the special audience I want to display special ads which might be more interesting for them.

So I gathered that I have to implement a custom ad system for my app. How can I best go on about it?
What view can I use to display my ads? I thought about showing them in animated gifs in a UIWebView and every time someone sees/taps the gif, I send a request to a webserver to increment a counter. Now I don't want the webserver to react to any request, but only to requests made from my app. How can I assure that? What technologies can I use?

Comment: Sounds more like a list of requirements rather than a specific problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an imageview to display ads, rest there are so many advertisements network providers where you can create your own ads, manage them, have a look on the visitors as well.
Some of the providers are, revmob, chartboost, admob etc.

Comment: I don't want to advertise anyhing. I want to display ads of others in my app.

Comment: Yes my friend, for that you can use the above providers for advertisements that i told you.

Comment: Try revmob or chartboost sdk, really simple to implement.